# Export a hi-res image from PhaserJS

Tags: javascript, image-processing, phaser-framework

I'm [creating graphics with PhaserJS](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/game-objects/graphics/primitives/arc-gradient-filled) and I need to export them either as a hi-res image or even better as a vector based one.

Example code:

```
var config = {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    type: Phaser.WEBGL,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    scene: {
        create: create
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function create ()
{
    var graphics = this.add.graphics();

    graphics.fillGradientStyle(0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 1);

    graphics.fillCircle(300, 300, 200);

    graphics.fillGradientStyle(0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xffff00, 0xffff00, 1);

    graphics.fillCircle(500, 300, 140);
}
```

How can this be done?
Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Since based on HTML5 `<canvas>` you won't get vector images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well with SVG it is not really possible (out-of-the-box), since phaser is based on HTML5 Canvas *(as **"Orkhan Alikhanov"** mentionin the comments)*.

To get a image from Phaser you can simply do this:

```
// get the phaser-canvas
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

// to start the download, you could ....
let downloadHelper = document.createElement('a');
downloadHelper.setAttribute('download', 'dowload.png');
downloadHelper.setAttribute('href', dataURL);
downloadHelper.click();
```

For **high-res**, just make the phaser application( the `width` and `height` of the game config) really big *(the final resolution you want)*.

**Sidenote:** If you want to save only a part of the canvas, checkout this post & answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69358678/1679286), it shows how to save parts of the phaser-canvas as an png file *(it uses the file saving library https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)*.

***That said,*** if you *would* only be using html5 canvas, you could use this libray http://gliffy.github.io/canvas2svg/ to create svg. This was mentioned in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/21069008/1679286 and seems to be a wrapper for the html5 canvas, **BUT** this *won't* work with phaser.  ***Update:** I might work, with if you are using `Phaser.CANVAS`. You could inject the context/canvas similar as in [this example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/game-config/custom-webgl-canvas)*, into the Phaser `config`

**Demo to create image from WebGL:**
*([Link to the documentation](https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.55.2/focus/Phaser.Core.Config-preserveDrawingBuffer))*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

    var config = {
        type: Phaser.WEBGL,
        width: 536,
        height: 183,
        // this property should/can be set
        preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
        physics: {
            default: 'arcade',
            arcade: {            
                gravity:{ y: 100 },
                debug: true
            }
        },
        scene: {
            create
        },
        banner: false
    }; 

    function create () {
        var graphics = this.add.graphics();

        graphics.fillGradientStyle(0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0x0000ff, 0x0000ff, 1);
        graphics.fillCircle(300, 300, 200);
        graphics.fillGradientStyle(0xff0000, 0xff0000, 0xffff00, 0xffff00, 1);
        graphics.fillCircle(500, 300, 140);
        
        this.input.on('pointerdown', _ => {
        let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    // to start the download, you could ....
    let downloadHelper = document.querySelector('#link');
         downloadHelper.setAttribute('download', 'dowload.png');
         downloadHelper.setAttribute('href', dataURL);
         
        });
    }

    new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
Right Click and select "Save Link as ..."<br>
<a id="link">DOWNLOAD </a> <br/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  For **const config = { type: Phaser.WEBGL** I get a black image as a result but for **Phaser.CANVAS** it works - is this expected or did I miss something? Unfortunately I can't use CANVAS because I need some WEBGL features.

Comment: @Tom I added a small demo, showing how you could get an Image from a Pahser app with `Phaser.WEBGL` set. Just use the property `preserveDrawingBuffer` to `true`.

Comment: @Tom, I just found this example https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/game-config/custom-canvas (you can pass a custom canvas and/or context), and wanted to see if this could work, setting the _MockContext_ from `http://gliffy.github.io/canvas2svg/`, and i theory it would work, but only with `Phaser.CANVAS`, with `type: Phaser.WEBGL`, it creates the svg-groups/elements, BUT seems to have issues with the gradient, so it creates black circles on a black background.